# UnicodeDecodeError again: 'utf-8' when debugging Python files in PyCharm Community

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, debugging, pycharm

**Current conclusion:**

The `encoding` of the `converted` file is `utf-8`->`utf-8 big`->`ansi` -> `utf-8`. **Reopen** the file after **each conversion**.

After observing for a period of time, there is **no such error**.

---

**Previous question:**

I mentioned this question before and also modified all the encoding options in the settings, but now it frequently appears in debug mode.

[older question's here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67190102/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-when-debugging-python-files-in-pycharm-community)

When I use PyCharm to debug .py files, the same file sometimes has UnicodeDecodeError, sometimes it’s normal. My operating system is Windows 10, PyCharm version is PyCharm 2021.1.2 (Community Edition).

The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 301, in _on_run
    r = r.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 1022-1023: unexpected end of data
```

I added a `try` `exception` to the file where the error was reported, and found that there were two errors.

Two lines of `print(e)` add `breakpoint`, `breakpoint` can print something but cannot pause debugging.

After finding the source file of the error, I saved it back and forth in `ansi`, `unicode big` and `utf-8` formats several times. It seems that the problem did not appear for the time being. To be observing.

```
if hasattr(r, 'decode'):
    try:
        r = r.decode('utf-8')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(r)

try:
    read_buffer += r
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print(r)
```

Comment: I think you should do a step back. What it is the problem? What it is the line in your code that give the error? What it is the data with error? (you have the position, you could copy the value there). Check the encoding of your file (not by randomly select a encoding in python): check metadata, open it on an editor and try different encoding, until you can read all file with correct characters (check position 1022-1023). Or are you just reading buffer of 1024 bytes at a time? A character may cross such boundary.

Comment: Yes, in the error message, `r` contains the file name, saying that the encoding of the target file is not UTF-8, but sometimes the encoding of the target file is indeed UTF-8, and it will be correct only if the encoding of the target file is converted several times. This problem still occurs occasionally. And the `pydevd_comm.py` file is the debug function itself, it cannot be suspended and stepped. But I did not check 1022-1023 of the target file, which is a good idea.